# finding the duration cycles in time series

Tags: python-3.x, time-series

I have a very long time series and want to identify how many time jumps and dips happen for different values :

3
4
5
1
0
3
4
6
7
2
3
0
6
7
4
3
2
1
0
2
3
5
4
5
6
5
7
0
8
2
1
4
0

I want to find the frequency of each cycle pair like the how many times value goes from
5 to 0 to 5
3 to 0 to 3

etc..

I have already tried cydets a library to find cycles but can't get what I want exactly.

```
from cydets.algorithm import detect_cycles

import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

pct_change_series = pct_change_series.round()
cycles = detect_cycles(pct_change_series.compute())
print(cycles)
```

Can you please help.

Comment: What is the desired output for the example provided?  Is the actual data all just integer values or are they some other data format (i.e. floats, timestamps, etc)

Answer (score 0):

This little script I wrote should do the trick. I made sure not to use any external libraries:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = [3,4,5,1,0,3,4,6,7,2,3,0,6,7,4,3,2,1,0,2,3,5,4,5,6,5,7,0,8,2,1,4,0]
    G = {i:[0,0] for i in data} # {i:(status, n_cycles) ... }
    for i in range(len(data)):
        nid, S, C = data[i], *G[data[i]]
        if nid == 0: G.update({i:[2,c] for i,(s,c) in G.items() if s==1}); continue
        elif G[nid][0] == 0: G.update({nid:[1,C]})
        elif G[nid][0] == 2: G.update({nid:[0,C+1]})
    [print(f'[{i}] Number of Cycles: {c}') for i,(s,c) in sorted(list(G.items()),key=lambda x:x[0]) if i>0]
```

When I run this, I get the following output:

```
[1] Number of Cycles: 2
[2] Number of Cycles: 3
[3] Number of Cycles: 3
[4] Number of Cycles: 4
[5] Number of Cycles: 1
[6] Number of Cycles: 2
[7] Number of Cycles: 2
[8] Number of Cycles: 0
```

For each number in your list, the number of cycles is the number of times that a number *x* appeared at position *i*, then some *m* numbers later a 0 appeared, then another *x* appeared *n* positions after the zero at position *(i+m+n)*. After each cycle is counted, this process restarts for *x*, meaning that now the next *x* cycle could potentially start from position *(i+m+n)*. Lmk if you want me to explain it in more detail!